# Combining Context with passing props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-context

Is it good practice to combine Context with passing props?

Use Context to avoid prop drilling

app.js -->  child 1 --> child 2 --> child 3

What if in addition you want to pass the same data just from

app.js --> child 1

Would it be ok to pass the same data as props even though we could use useContext inside child 1?

Thank you!